# Add CFLAGS to QMake project without hard-coding them in the .pro file?

Tags: environment-variables, qmake

I'm using a distributed compiler, and I need to add `-m64` to `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. Usually, my definitions in *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* are fine, but [qmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake) ignores them for some reason. The standard way of doing this seems to be to edit the .pro file, but I obviously don't want to hard code the architecture. So, I *can* edit the .pro file, but I can't hard code anything in it.

I tried setting CXXFLAGS like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $(CFLAGS)
```

But it says:

> Makefile:17: *** Recursive variable `CXXFLAGS' references itself (eventually).  Stop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't need `$(ENV_VAR)`, but `$$(ENV_VAR)`, so I added these to my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$(CXXFLAGS)
QMAKE_CFLAGS += $$(CFLAGS)
QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$(LDFLAGS)
```

This makes qmake respect those environment variables. Note that qmake uses `LFLAGS` instead of `LDFLAGS`.

This is still not ideal, because you can need to rerun `qmake` to change the environment variables, instead of having `make` handle them intelligently, but it's definitely better than having to edit the *.pro* file every time.